# How to fix MongoDB connection Error in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Hey, does Anyone face a MongoDB connection error/issue on AWS lambda?
and if you know the solution, please help me, guys!

my code works perfectly in my local system!

But when I try to post, using the API gateway endpoint, MongoDB disconnect! ( session time-out error )

[image: Image description]

[image: Image description]

Comment: I don't think it is a session timeout error since according to the timestamp, there was less then 30s that have passed. My thinking is more around reusing the same connection between two lambda invocations. Can you try to do a disconnect before terminating the lambda?

Comment: i don't get your point! can you please explain

Comment: Everytime you invoke a lambda, there is a whole execution environment that is created for your lambda to be able to run. This execution environment would be shared across the next lambda invocation (so that you don't have a cold start on every lambda execution). In your case, you trigger the lambda within the same execution environment which result in reusing the same runtime context between invocation. It is like your are doing two time mongoose.connect(). When you do on your laptop, the whole execution context is deleted so it works fine. Please disconnect before ending the lambda.

Comment: what you could do as well, is moving the connect outside of the handler. So that the same client is being used across the same lambda execution context.

Comment: ok, i call connectDB() inside of handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your code that doesn't take care of [lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html).

As mentioned in the comment above, between two lambda invocation, you are not releasing the connection to the DB. It is like doing two times in a row  `mongoose.connect()`

I suggest to do something like this:

```
let cachedClient = null;

async function connectDB() {
  if (cachedClient) {
    return cachedClient;
  }

  // Connect to our MongoDB database hosted on MongoDB Atlas
  const client = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB_URL);

  cachedClient = client;
  return client;
}
```

This will reuse the same client across multiple lambda invocation (within the same execution environment). When a new lambda execution environment is created, `cachedClient` will be null and a new client will be created.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: it's want not brother! but another new error now: ```Serverless SDK Warning: Following trace spans didn't end before end of lambda invocation: node.http.request```

Comment: share your updated code please. Otherwise, as I mentioned before, call mongoose.disconnect() after printing Mongo Connected.

Comment: ![db.js pic](https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/hc9bv68cp6uc912juukv.png)



![index.js pic](https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/40rbdhr6i5t4jkuk39ko.png)

Comment: Ok, then try something like this:

`let cachedClient = null;

async function connectDB() {
  if (cachedClient) {
    console.log('MongoDB connected')
  }
 else {
  // Connect to our MongoDB database hosted on MongoDB Atlas
  const client = await mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB_URL);

  cachedClient = client;
console.log('MongoDB connected')
  }
}
`

Comment: ohm! really sorry brother!  now my code work! my GitHub ci/cd is failed! so i can't deploy new code! i testing my old code!  really thank you  : ) @brnaba 
if you free, can you answer in dev.to it will helpfull for many developers https:// dev. to /jacksonkasi/ how-to-fix-mongodb-connection-error-in-aws-lambda-i8d

Comment: I don't have an account there. But I guess you can put a link to this post.